# I have a yaml file.I need to trigger everyday with website datas how can I do?

Tags: web, deployment

I have a yaml file with build stage, but I need a deploy stage for trigger everyday at 16.00 with website (on the internet) datas. How can I write a valid deploy stage?

```
//gitlab.ci.yaml file and build stage. I need a deploy stage to use trigger as a service.


variables:
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Tools\Nuget\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe'

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - "cd Source"

build_job:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore'
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH"  Textbox_ComboBox.sln /nologo /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug'
```

I expect the everyday at 16.00 datas are updated with on the internet website datas how can I fix the yaml file (taking datas on website is important).

Comment: You might be looking for https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html

Comment: ı understand it but i cant understand how to take datas from internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f) you should be able to achieve what you want.

To answer more specifically to your question **how to send data to Gitlab**, you need to configure a Gitlab runner that will run your jobs and send the results back to GitLab. You can follow the official documentation [right here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html).

After the Gitlab runner if installed, you should be able to see it in Gitlab, in `Settings > CI/CD`.

Then configure your schedule following the official documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/schedules.html) and using your gitlab-ci.yaml file.